# Filter dataframe to get the leaves of tree structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns for levels of hierarchy (similar to directory path). I am trying to keep only the records with the latest generation in the levels (leaves of the hierarchy tree). I tried couple ways with transform and groupby but unable to get the desired output

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'lvl1':['aa','aa','aa','aa','bb','bb','bb','bb','cc','aa'],
                   'lvl2':[np.nan,'xx','xx','xx',np.nan,'yy','yy','zz',np.nan,'sa'],
                   'lvl3':[np.nan,np.nan,'ww','qq',np.nan,np.nan,'rr',np.nan,np.nan,'jj'],
                   'value':[12,4,7,22,76,0,18,47,10,2]})
result = pd.DataFrame({'lvl1':['aa','aa','bb','bb','cc','aa'],
                       'lvl2':['xx','xx','yy','zz',np.nan,'sa'],
                       'lvl3':['ww','qq','rr',np.nan,np.nan,'jj'],
                       'value':[7,22,18,47,10,2]})
```

**Figure**

[image: figure]

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

If need filter rows by maximum unique values per rows and for each category not maximum only last row use:

```
s = df[["lvl1", "lvl2", "lvl3"]].nunique(axis=1)
#if need test number of non missing values use count
#s = df[["lvl1", "lvl2", "lvl3"]].count(axis=1)

df = df[~s.duplicated(keep='last') | s.eq(s.max())]
print (df)
  lvl1 lvl2 lvl3  value
2   aa   xx   ww      7
3   aa   xx   qq     22
6   bb   yy   rr     18
7   bb   zz  NaN     47
8   cc  NaN  NaN     10
9   aa   sa   jj      2
```

Comment: Could you please clarify how this works cause I have tried to implement this on my actual dataframe and it did not work as it filtered only the rows with the 3 levels filled but cases where its only two levels or one, were filtered out.

Comment: @Youstanzr - first - do you need rows if check `print (s)` with maximum value and then last duplicated rows? Or need something else?

Comment: @Youstanzr - or maybe need `s = df[["lvl1", "lvl2", "lvl3"]].count(axis=1)` instead `s = df[["lvl1", "lvl2", "lvl3"]].nunique(axis=1)`

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment clearly. What I am trying to capture the leaves of a tree structure which is formed in levels as shown. I tried both the count and nunique but both result in same result. Leaves are not captured for every branch but instead only captured at the branch where it has 3 levels. Your approach works on the example but not my actual dataframe even though the structure is very similar. I'm currently debugging to find why it works on the example but not my actual df

Comment: @Youstanzr - simple question - is possible missing values in first column and not in second or third?

Comment: It is not possible have no value in lvl1 but it is possible to have lvl1 or lvl2 or lvl3 to be a leaf

Comment: @Youstanzr - yes, I think there are 3 options for columns `first=notNaN, second=notNaN, third=notNaN` `first=notNaN, second=notNaN, third=NaN` `first=notNaN, second=NaN, third=NaN`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245845/discussion-between-youstanzr-and-jezrael).